# Why did 18th-century readers judge Gothic literature countercultural or 'Gothic'?

Tags: historical-context

[Dr. Lilia Melani](http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/english/melani/gothic/gothic.html) admits that

> **[1.] To most modern readers**, however, ***The Castle of Otranto* is dull reading; except for the villain Manfred, the characters are insipid; the action moves at a fast clip with no emphasis or suspense**, despite the supernatural manifestations and a young maiden's flight through dark vaults. **[2.] But contemporary readers found the novel electrifying original and thrillingly suspenseful**, with its remote setting, its use of the supernatural, and its medieval trappings, all of which have been so frequently imitated and so poorly imitated that they have become stereotypes.

Why's 2 true? How weren't the masterworks beneath just as electrifying, original, suspenseful, which  educated [Georgians](http://www.intriguing-history.com/periods-history/) would've read?  All page numbers refer to [*The Well-Educated Mind*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/039308096X) (2 edn 2016).

3. (p. 89) John Bunyan's *The Pilgrim's Progress* (1607)  features "the monster Apollyon", "goblins who haunt the Valley of the Shadow of Death", and "another pilgrim taken to a mysterious door at the city's foot and thrust through: "Then I saw," he ends, soberly, "that there was a way to Hell, even from the Gates of Heaven."
4. (p. 280) Aeschylus's *Agamenon* (c. 458 BC) features "the goddess Artemis, who loved Troy, blew great winds on the fleet to keep the Greeks from sailing."  Then Agamenon sacrified "daughter Iphigenia" "Against the wild objections of his wife." Agamenon's "father, Atreus, punished Agamenon's brother Thyestes for sleeping with Atresus' wife by roasting Thyestes' children and serving them to his brother."

Other supernatural thrillers  are Marlowe's *Doctor Faustus* (p. 287) and *Beowulf* (p. 359).

---

p. 64:

> In the nineteenth century, the soap opera of choice was the “Gothic novel,” a story of mystery and vague supernatural threat, set in fantastic and menacing places (or in central Europe, which, for most readers, amounted to the same thing). Gothic heroines languished in ruined castles, threatened by ancient spells, insane wives, and mysterious noblemen who avoid sunlight and mirrors. Here is Emily of the wildly popular *The Mysteries of Udolpho*: plucky but not too bright, wandering through the strange echoing castle of Count Morano.

Prof. [Ellen Malenas Ledoux](https://ledoux.camden.rutgers.edu/cv/) outlines [here](https://news.camden.rutgers.edu/2013/07/english-professor-authors-book-examining-social-reform-in-gothic-writing/) that Gothic literature:

> “explore the darker impulses of human nature, such as paranoia, barbarism and the taboo,” explains Ledoux. “Some of the markers of Gothic literature aren’t often what one would think; it doesn’t have to be supernatural, but deals with confusion about boundaries, such as those between what is alive and dead, or animal and human.”
>
> "us[s]e dark elements to uncover social atrocities, or to offer alternative solutions to these issues. “In a fantasy world, you can offer an alternative vision of something that you can’t through realistic writing,” explains Ledoux.
>
> Informed by genre and reader-response theories, the [Ledoux's] book illustrates how Gothic scenes depicting violence and heightened emotion challenged conventional thinking and normative behaviors, revealing the Gothic’s transgressive spirit as a dynamic force within the sociopolitical landscape of the 18th- and 19th-century Atlantic world.

[This Ted-ed video at 4:48](https://youtu.be/STOJftffOqs?t=4m48s) and [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-goth-and-gothic/answer/Anna-Szpak-2?share=2c416bb7) instance the polysemy of 'Gothic', but they and [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Gothic?ref=etymonline_crossreference) don't  headline the underlying semantic notions.

> The history of the word gothic is embedded
>   in thousands of years worth of countercultural movements,
>   from invading outsiders becoming kings
>   to towering spires replacing solid columns
>   to artists finding beauty in darkness.

Comment: I find it interesting that *all* of your examples are either a century or more older, or not a novel at all (*Doctor Faustus* is a play, not a novel). Do you have any contemporary examples?

Comment: I haven't read The Castle of Otranto, but man, have you read Pilgrim's Progress? It's dull. (Then again, I read it when I was younger. But still. The whole plot can be ascertained by just looking at the character names, and it's all swallowed in deathly prose.) Beowulf to me was rather exciting, but it wasn't fully translated until around 1815, and The Castle of Otranto was from 1764. Doctor Faustus, as another comment points out, is a play, not a book, and would have been seen not read (this then is like comparing a movie's excitement to that of a book's - quite different).

Comment: @muru Can you recommend equally suspenseful and countercultural novels? I couldn't contemplate any, as novels are relatively newer compared to plays and poems. Perhaps *Don Quixote*, but that's not in English?